# Bootstrap scrollspy not working doesnt highlight at all

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone take a look at my html? Previously, my scrollspy was working but I dont know what happend and its not working anymore. I have been at this for 2 hours and I still can't get it to work. I dont recall doing any breaking changes.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Nate The Great</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Istok+Web|Lora" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='./assets/img/favicon.ico' />

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" >

    <!--Start of Navigation Bar-->
    <div class="navbar transparent pull-right navbar-fixed-top" id="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p class="navbar-brand " id="brand"> <img src="./assets/img/profile.jpg" alt="" style="display: inline; margin-right: 3px; border-radius:50%">Nathaniel D Alcedo Jr</p>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="https://ndaljr.github.io/blog">Blog</a></li>   will workk on this-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Navigation Bar-->

    <!--Landing Page-->
    <div id='home'>
        <h1>
            Nathaniel D Alcedo Jr,
        </h1>

        <h2 >aspiring web developer</h2>
    </div>
    <!--End of Landing Page-->


    <div class="text-center" id="portfolio">
        <h1>Projects Finished</h1>
        <p>Free Code Camp <a href="./calculator"><u>Calculator</u></a></p>

    </div>

    <div class="pull-left" id="about">
        <h1>A little about me</h1>
        <p>
            Hello there! As the title suggests, I am an aspiring web developer.
            I'm currently serving my time in the Singapore Armed Forces and in my free time, I like to muck
            around on the computer. It ranges from making mock websites to thinking of my own implementations
            of basic data structures. I find pleasure in breaking code and trying to fix them using stackoverflow.<br><br>
            My first contact with a programming languges was in polytechnic during a module on c++. How I sucked terriby!
            It wasn't until halfway through my time in national service did I take an interest in programming once again. I'm currently
            doing Free Code Camp's course on web development in my free time. I turn operationally ready in may of 2017 and I intend to 
            look for a job in this wonderful field we call software development.
            </p>

    </div>

    <!--Start ofFooter Bar-->
    <!--
    <footer class="footer pull-left navbar-fixed-bottom">    TODO: PLACE THIS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE TOTAL PAGE
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <p>Copyright &copy Nathaniel</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>   
    </footer>-->

    <!--End of Footer Bar-->
    <script src="./assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c1a4d3ec73.js"></script>
    <script>
        // This script enalbes the smooth scrolling of pages when clicking links on the Navbar
         $(function() {
            $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
                    return false;
                    }
                 }
             });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `.navbar-default` class to the navbar as well as change your **id** of `id="navigation"` to reflect the `data-target`, currently it's `data-target="#navbar"`.

**Currently there isn't enough content to actually scroll so a generic height is set for example purposes.

**Working Example:** *Open to FullPage*

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand span,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
  display: inline-block;
}
section {
  padding-top: 70px;
  min-height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/000" alt=""> <span>Nathaniel D Alcedo Jr</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <section id='home'>
      <h1>Nathaniel D Alcedo Jr,</h1>
      <h2>aspiring web developer</h2>
    </section>

    <section class="text-center" id="portfolio">
      <h1>Projects Finished</h1>
      <p>Free Code Camp <a href="./calculator"><u>Calculator</u></a>
      </p>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
      <h1>A little about me</h1>
      <p>
        Hello there! As the title suggests, I am an aspiring web developer. I'm currently serving my time in the Singapore Armed Forces and in my free time, I like to muck around on the computer. It ranges from making mock websites to thinking of my own implementations
        of basic data structures. I find pleasure in breaking code and trying to fix them using stackoverflow.
        <br>
        <br>My first contact with a programming languges was in polytechnic during a module on c++. How I sucked terriby! It wasn't until halfway through my time in national service did I take an interest in programming once again. I'm currently doing Free
        Code Camp's course on web development in my free time. I turn operationally ready in may of 2017 and I intend to look for a job in this wonderful field we call software development.
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>

  <footer class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          TODO: PLACE THIS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE TOTAL PAGE
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p>Copyright &copy; Nathaniel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p>Trademark &reg; Nathaniel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p>Something Nathaniel</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p>Something Nathaniel</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```